# Teammate on different turn?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing with my kid on the local network option. I'm a bit confused because I thought the games would be synced but I'm 5 turns ahead of him. When he quit the game and rejoined, he had the same number of turns as me, so what happened during the 5 turns that he skipped?

Also, not synchronizing the turns is confusing to me. How does that even work on this kind of game? It seems I can be in, say, 1500AD, while he's in 2000BC.

Comment: It shouldn't happen.  There seems to be quite a few posts on other sites about desync like this.  It sounds like though you found what some of those posts suggested already though, which was to quit and rejoin.  It sounds like you will need to just keep an eye out for this.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yeah I saw some other posts about this, specifically this is something that happens with the "simultaneous" turn option and not with "dynamic" turn option. But I'm still confused. I was on turn 62 and he was on turn 57, and when he quit and rejoined, he got bumped up to turn 62 as well. Are you suggesting that the 57 was a display error and that he was actually on turn 62?

Comment: No, I think its really desynced, and not a display issue.  In the time I played Civ 6, I haven't had this issue, though I never played on LAN.

Comment: @TimmyJim Ah I see. Any guesses as to what happened in those 5 turns that he skipped?

Comment: @anonuser01 Your game desynced.  Meaning that since the desync you two were playing different games with the other's nation controlled by the AI.  When he quit (ending his version of the game) and rejoined, he took over for the AI that was temporarily in charge of his nation since the desync.  As his game was at an earlier turn, it may have been better for you to join him instead.  Or for you both to go back to an autosave from before the desync.

Comment: @tjd Last night, we run into the "desync" issue, which I think is different from what I posted in the OP. What happened last night was that we were on the same turn, and I received a notification that we're desynced, and then my son had to rejoin the game